# The absolute convergence of (say) $\sum\limits_{n \in \mathbb Z} f(x+n)dx$ when $f$ is continuous and in $L^1(\mathbb R)$

Tags: integration, measure-theory, topological-groups, locally-compact-groups, haar-measure

Here is a basic theorem from locally compact topological groups.  Suppose $G$ is a locally compact abelian topological group with closed subgroup $H$, and Haar measures $dg$ and $dh$.  Suppose that $f: G \rightarrow \mathbb C$ is integrable.  Then for almost all $g \in G$, the integral $\int\limits_H f(gh)dh$ converges absolutely and becomes an integrable function of $gH$ on the quotient group $G/H$ with respect to its Haar measure $d\bar{g}$.  Furthermore, we have

$$\int\limits_G f(g)dg = \int\limits_{G/H} \int\limits_H f(gh)dh d\bar{g}$$

This is proved first when $f$ is continuous and compactly supported, and then extended to arbitrary $f \in L^1(G)$ by density.

I was wondering whether there is anything more about this that can be said when $f$ is not only integrable, but also continuous on $G$.  If it makes the results nicer, let's assume $G$ is $\sigma$-compact.  If it makes it even nicer, let's assume $G = \mathbb R$ and $H = \mathbb Z$.

Assuming $f: G \rightarrow \mathbb C$ is continuous and integrable...

- Is $\int\limits_H f(gh)dh$ absolutely convergent for **all** $g \in G$?
- Is $g \mapsto \int\limits_H f(gh)dh$ continuous?
- If $\int\limits_H f(gh)dh$ is absolutely convergent for all $g \in G$, is $g \mapsto \int\limits_H f(gh)dh$ continuous?

Comment: no try with $f(x)=\sum_n n\phi (n^2(x−n))$ where $\phi \in C^\infty_c([-1/2,1/2]),\phi(0)=1$. If $f \in L^1$ and $f' \in L^\infty$ then $f= o(1)$, if $ (1+|x|^{1+\epsilon}) f' \in L^\infty$ then $f = o(1/x^{1+\epsilon})$ and $\sum_n f(x+n)$ converges absolutely and locally uniformly.